# How to avoid shape error when I change Keras' backend from Theano to Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, keras

I tried to use Deep Semantic Similarity Model(DSSM): https://github.com/airalcorn2/Deep-Semantic-Similarity-Model/blob/master/deep_semantic_similarity_keras.py on Keras using **Tensorflow** backend. The code is for Keras using Theano backend and works without any errors on it.

To make it run on Keras using Tensorflow backend correctly, I modified some Tensor attributes as:

```
-: backend.dot(x, backend.transpose(y)) / (x.norm(2) * y.norm(2)) 
+: backend.dot(backend.l2_normalize(x, 0), backend.transpose(backend.l2_normalize(y, 0)))
```

and

```
-: x.max(axis = 1) 
+: backend.max(x, 1)
```

When I compiled the modified model, **ValueError: logits and targets must have the same shape (() vs (?, ?))** occurred. How can I avoid the error?

Here is the modified code

```
import keras
import numpy as np

from keras import backend
from keras.layers import Input, merge
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Lambda, Reshape
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution1D
from keras.models import Model

def R(vects):
    (x, y) = vects
    return backend.dot(backend.l2_normalize(x, 0), backend.transpose(backend.l2_normalize(y, 0)))

LETTER_GRAM_SIZE = 3
WINDOW_SIZE = 3 
TOTAL_LETTER_GRAMS = int(3 * 1e4)
WORD_DEPTH = WINDOW_SIZE * TOTAL_LETTER_GRAMS
K = 300
L = 128
J = 4
FILTER_LENGTH = 1

query = Input(shape = (None, WORD_DEPTH))
pos_doc = Input(shape = (None, WORD_DEPTH))
neg_docs = [Input(shape = (None, WORD_DEPTH)) for j in range(J)]

query_conv = Convolution1D(K, FILTER_LENGTH, border_mode = "same", input_shape = (None, WORD_DEPTH), activation = "tanh")(query) # See equation (2).

query_max = Lambda(lambda x: backend.max(x, 1), output_shape = (K, ))(query_conv) 

query_sem = Dense(L, activation = "tanh", input_dim = K)(query_max) 

doc_conv = Convolution1D(K, FILTER_LENGTH, border_mode = "same", input_shape = (None, WORD_DEPTH), activation = "tanh")
doc_max = Lambda(lambda x: backend.max(x, 1), output_shape = (K, ))
doc_sem = Dense(L, activation = "tanh", input_dim = K)

pos_doc_conv = doc_conv(pos_doc)
neg_doc_convs = [doc_conv(neg_doc) for neg_doc in neg_docs]

pos_doc_max = doc_max(pos_doc_conv)
neg_doc_maxes = [doc_max(neg_doc_conv) for neg_doc_conv in neg_doc_convs]

pos_doc_sem = doc_sem(pos_doc_max)
neg_doc_sems = [doc_sem(neg_doc_max) for neg_doc_max in neg_doc_maxes]

R_layer = Lambda(R, output_shape = (1, )) 

R_Q_D_p = R_layer([query_sem, pos_doc_sem])
R_Q_D_ns = [R_layer([query_sem, neg_doc_sem]) for neg_doc_sem in neg_doc_sems]

concat_Rs = merge([R_Q_D_p] + R_Q_D_ns, mode = "concat")
concat_Rs = Reshape((J + 1, 1))(concat_Rs)

weight = np.array([1]).reshape(1, 1, 1, 1)
with_gamma = Convolution1D(1, 1, border_mode = "same", input_shape = (J + 1, 1), activation = "linear", bias = False, weights = [weight])(concat_Rs) 

exponentiated = Lambda(lambda x: backend.exp(x), output_shape = (J + 1, ))(with_gamma) # See equation (5).
exponentiated = Reshape((J + 1, ))(exponentiated)

prob = Lambda(lambda x: x[0][0] / backend.sum(x[0]), output_shape = (1, ))(exponentiated) 

model = Model(input = [query, pos_doc] + neg_docs, output = prob)
model.compile(optimizer = "adadelta", loss = "binary_crossentropy")
```

and error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/jun/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in merge_with(self, other)
    571       try:
--> 572         self.assert_same_rank(other)
    573         new_dims = []

/Users/jun/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in assert_same_rank(self, other)
    617         raise ValueError(
--> 618             "Shapes %s and %s must have the same rank" % (self, other))
    619 

ValueError: Shapes (?, ?) and () must have the same rank

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/jun/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn.py in sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, targets, name)
    430     try:
--> 431       targets.get_shape().merge_with(logits.get_shape())
    432     except ValueError:

/Users/jun/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in merge_with(self, other)
    578         raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are not compatible" %
--> 579                          (self, other))
    580 

ValueError: Shapes (?, ?) and () are not compatible

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a4001289be07> in <module>()
     61 
     62 model = Model(input = [query, pos_doc] + neg_docs, output = prob)
---> 63 model.compile(optimizer = "adadelta", loss = "binary_crossentropy")

/Users/jun/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, **kwargs)
    628             loss_weight = loss_weights_list[i]
    629             output_loss = weighted_loss(y_true, y_pred,
--> 630                                         sample_weight, mask)
    631             if len(self.outputs) > 1:
    632                 self.metrics_tensors.append(output_loss)

/Users/jun/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in weighted(y_true, y_pred, weights, mask)
    330     def weighted(y_true, y_pred, weights, mask=None):
    331         # score_array has ndim >= 2
--> 332         score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
    333         if mask is not None:
    334             # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in theano

/Users/jun/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/objectives.py in binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
     46 
     47 def binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
---> 48     return K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true), axis=-1)
     49 
     50 

/Users/jun/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in binary_crossentropy(output, target, from_logits)
   1464         output = tf.clip_by_value(output, epsilon, 1 - epsilon)
   1465         output = tf.log(output / (1 - output))
-> 1466     return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(output, target)
   1467 
   1468 

/Users/jun/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn.py in sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, targets, name)
    432     except ValueError:
    433       raise ValueError("logits and targets must have the same shape (%s vs %s)"
--> 434                        % (logits.get_shape(), targets.get_shape()))
    435 
    436     # The logistic loss formula from above is

ValueError: logits and targets must have the same shape (() vs (?, ?))
```

Comment: I asked our resident Keras expert, and his response was: Looking at the error message and code, one can infer that the final output `prob` is a scalar, whereas it should be a 2D array (one scalar probability per batch entry). The problem is likely to be at line `prob = Lambda(lambda x: x[0][0] / backend.sum(x[0]), output_shape = (1, ))(exponentiated)`

Comment: I noticed that the batch mode SGD won't work with that definition of 'prob'.  Did you make it work with batches as well?

Comment: @PeteWarden - could you upgrade your comment to an answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(Converted from a comment to an answer at @dga's request)

I asked our resident Keras expert, and his response was: Looking at the error message and code, one can infer that the final output prob is a scalar, whereas it should be a 2D array (one scalar probability per batch entry). The problem is likely to be at line

```
prob = Lambda(lambda x: x[0][0] / backend.sum(x[0]), output_shape = (1, ))(exponentiated)
```